# Problem building to IOS with Flutter in Android Studio

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter

friends...

For reasons I don't know why... When I am building to iOS Emulator, I have this error:

Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳

```
/Users/user./.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_sign_in-4.1.1/ios/Classes/FLTGoogleSignInPlugin.m:139:19: warning: unused variable 'sourceApplication' [-Wunused-variable]


        NSString *sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey];


                  ^
1 warning generated.
ld: framework not found App
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description


warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
```

Comment: Looks like you are having permission issues, have you updated info.plist for using image_picker?

Comment: Hi man... I did not update anything... Yesterday this start to happen with a lot more errors and In don't know why.

Comment: Okay, look like you have run the app before and it did not give issues. Permission issues are not the reason maybe. Try to clean the build and build it again. Use flutter clean in your terminal, and then flutter run.